# How to write the fizzbuzz test using recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing this problem for school and I think I have it done but I'd like to get some more eyes on it before I turn it in. Did I do it correctly? Is this good code? Is there a more efficient way of doing it? How could I improve?

The instructions are as follows.

Use RECURSION to write this function (or make this function a wrapper over another recursive function)

```
 * this function prints the appropriate FizzBuzz values (feel free to
 * call the provided FizzBuzz function) for values from from to to, 
 * including both of those values. Each value should be printed in a separate line.
 * Example: printFizzBuzz(2,6) would print:
 * 2
 * Fizz
 * 4
 * Buzz
 * Fizz 
 */

public static void printFizzBuzz(int from, int to, PrintStream out)
    if(from <= to){
        if(from % 3 == 0 && from % 5 == 0){
            System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
        } else if(from % 3 == 0){
            System.out.println("Fizz");
        } else if(from % 5 == 0){
            System.out.println("Buzz"); 
        } else {
            System.out.println(from);
        }
         printFizzBuzz(++from, to, out);
    }
```

Comment: This question would be better asked in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18820/what-do-you-think-of-my-recursive-fizzbuzz

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an opening `{` (and a closing `}`) to your method body; you aren't writing to your `PrintStream out`; and you could perform the modulus operations once and save the result in `boolean`(s). I think you wanted something like,

```
public static void printFizzBuzz(int from, int to, PrintStream out) {
    if (from <= to) {
        boolean mod3 = ((from % 3) == 0);
        boolean mod5 = ((from % 5) == 0);
        if (mod3 && mod5) {
            out.println("FizzBuzz");
        } else if (mod3) {
            out.println("Fizz");
        } else if (mod5) {
            out.println("Buzz");
        } else {
            out.println(from);
        }
        printFizzBuzz(++from, to, out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. Duh, can't believe I missed the braces. Thanks for the heads up on using my printstream.out. Cool! Saving the results in booleans definitely makes things simpler in the if/else statements. Thanks!